# Question about hyperlinking a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I can make the button appear after 5 seconds. I'd like to be able to click the button and go to a different site (like google.com, for example). Help please?

```
<style type="text/css">

#buy_button_image { display: none; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{
var img = document.getElementById("buy_button_image");
var _t = function() {
    img.style.display = "block";
};
window.setTimeout(_t, 5000);
window.clearTimeout(_t);
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
<img style="border: medium none ;" id="buy_button_image" src="http://www.pumaskills.com/images/redgetaccessnow-vip.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<img style="border: medium none ;" id="buy_button_image" src="http://www.pumaskills.com/images/redgetaccessnow-vip.png">
```

To:

```
<div id="buy_button_image"><a href="http://google.com/"><img style="border: medium none ;" id="buy_button_image" src="http://www.pumaskills.com/images/redgetaccessnow-vip.png"></a></div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the `a` tag in a `div`? Seems superfluous.

Comment: @peter you don't have to, I like to do it because then you are explicitly hiding all the elements in the div. It makes it easier to then go back and make changes later. For instance someone wants some other element or text that shouldn't be linked but should still display the same way as the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `a` tag:

Note that your clearTimeout does nothing. Take a look at the **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)** and **[`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout)** references.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">    
    #buy_button_image { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("buy_button_image");
    var _t = function() {
        img.style.display = "block";
    };
    window.setTimeout(_t, 5000);
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.pumaskills.com" id="buy_button_image">
        <img style="border: medium none ;" src="http://www.pumaskills.com/images/redgetaccessnow-vip.png">
    </a>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### **[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6A97/)**

Comment: Thank you Peter. This worked perfectly. I appreciate the help from everyone!

Comment: @Yemi - Glad to hear it ;) Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem (check mark outline right below the votes of an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag?

```
<style type="text/css">

#buy_button_image { display: none; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{
var img = document.getElementById("buy_button_image");
var _t = function() {
    img.style.display = "block";
};
window.setTimeout(_t, 5000);
window.clearTimeout(_t);
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><img style="border: medium none ;" id="buy_button_image" src="http://www.pumaskills.com/images/redgetaccessnow-vip.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that will work but the anchor tag would still be "visible" in the page. Someone could accidentally click it or select it.

Comment: @Cfreak - not if the anchor tag is set to display none and the image is inside - see my answer.

Comment: @Peter that's not what his solution shows. His a tag has no id attached

Comment: @Cfreak - Exactly. I am suggesting something else, which is attaching the ID to the `A` tag and setting the visibility of the `A` tag to `none`.

Comment: @Cfreak and @Peter - yeah sure, those are better solutions. I didn't spend, well, any time on it because it shows 5 seconds after page load, and I'm sure he would learn better by figuring out that by himself. However, you are both absolutely right.